# open source software which converts english statements to shell script

Tags: machine-learning, shell-scripting

I am looking for open source software that will auto convert english statements to shell scripts

ex:

english statement `get current processes running on linux system`

It should automatically give me sample code

sample shell script `$ ps aux`

Comment: Why Open Source? Do intend to change it? If so, why not code it from scratch?

Comment: Checking if already any software exist to avoid duplicate efforts

Comment: If you find something, please post & accept an answer, as that will help others in future. Good luck :-)